# Intel XTU voltage and frequency stuck at 0

Tags: overclocking, undervolting

A while back, I was testing out intel XTU, and everything was great. I used it to undervolt my I7-8086k, and it worked flawlessly, I don't remember how much exactly, but it ran a bit cooler ☺
Fast forward a bit, and I decide to try my hand at overclocking it too, so I put the `Core Voltage Offset` to 0, and put the `Ratio Multiplier` up to 50x, and It bumped right on up to 5ghz ☺
Fast forward a bit more, and I'm steady bumping down the voltage, and running a stress test for 2-3 hours. After a while, I figured id jump down to -0.200V on the `core voltage offset`, and my pc instantly froze, then restarted. oops, no problem, ill just not put it down that low next time.
But when I restarted my pc, and loaded everything back up, the

```
Core voltage, 
Max Core Frequency, 
Package Temperature,
Package TDP, 
Core TDP, 
Active Core Count, 
Core 0-5 Temp and Utilization (not the CPU utilization monitor though)
and Processor cache frequency
```

were all stuck at 0, which clearly wasn't right...
Additionally, the CPU Utilization monitor seems to update ***WAY*** faster then before, almost glitch-ily fast --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5sqO.gif.
My question is, is there any way to make it start reading those values correctly again?
I'm mostly certain that the issue isn't the CPU itself, since programs like realtemp show the temp correctly, and the task manager shows the frequency.
I did just update XTU to 7.4.0.26, and this did not change or fix the issue.